# Why does user-agent keep changing PID and losing my keys?

Tags: github, jenkins, ssh, rsa, ssh-agent

Big picture: Trying to connect GitHub to Jenkins. 
Jenkins is running on Ubuntu under user Jenkins.(I log in as Pierre, then change to user Jenkins)

I'm following [This Guide](https://gist.github.com/misterbrownlee/3708738) to connect the two. 
I'm trying to generate keys from Jenkins commandline.
I used

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C 'pierre@myplace.com'
```

to generate the key and used standard config. But Then when I try to connect to GitHub I get the following:

```
jenkins@Desktop:~$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 6328
jenkins@Desktop:~$ ssh-add -l -E md5
The agent has no identities.
jenkins@Desktop:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa)
jenkins@Desktop:~$ ssh-add -l -E md5
2048 MD5:ad:1f:9d:5c:b5:cc:8e:bb:06:5b:c2:5e:68:67:77:24 /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
jenkins@Desktop:~$ ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).
jenkins@Desktop:~$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 6353
jenkins@Desktop:~$ ssh-add -l -E md5
The agent has no identities.
```

=> even after manually adding the keys to the ssh-agent, it will not connect!

1) What's going on with the changing PID of the agent?

2) Why is it losing its identities?

3) Why isn't it connecting?

Comment: This question is off-topic here, it belongs on superuser.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to questions 1 and 2 are the same: each `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` is starting a new ssh agent each time.  The `eval` executes the text outputted at that point as shell commands, causing it to define new environment variables that tell `ssh-add` and `ssh` how to use the new ssh agent (which also removes the information about how to use the any other ssh agents you had started previously, though they remain running).

I don't know the answer to question 3, but it seems odd that you are trying to ssh directly to `git@github.com`, and I can't find where in the guide you posted that it tells you to do that.  AIUI, `git@github.com` is not something you are supposed to ssh to, but instead something that just appears in URLs of Gitlab projects, but I could be wrong.

Comment: This is the explanation I was hoping to get - I managed to figure out #3: I had to configure the public key in github.com, which allowed me to connect (had to go and copy paste from the public key and paste it in the settings section of my account on github.com)